# Convert row to columns in the same table and delete the row from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

how to select rows from a table by converting matching rows to columns within the same table and delete the row from the table. There are 4 Account number (100,200,111,222) where account number 100 is associated to 111 and account number 200 is associated to 222. Here each company account(200) is associated with sister company account(222).Please refer to below pic for original table and expected result. There could be rows which has no associated companies. End result should have if a company has associated rows they need to be converted to columns in one line and individual rows as well. I tried using Pivot but unable to achieve the result. Any suggestions could help

[Table structure and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM7eu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use self join and analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.comapny, t.acct, t.amount,
       S.comapny as company_1, s.acct as acct_1,  s.amount as amount_1,
       Row_number() 
         over (partition by least(t.comapny, s.comapny) order by t.amount) as rn
  From your_table t
  Left join your_table s on t.sister_company = s.company) t
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: Tried your solution, it's complaining - The column 'Company' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: Ok. That was because of same name in subquery. Updated the answer. Check now!!

Comment: Almost there, Thank you. I need to  display like left side  Acc No. 200 from t table and 222 from s table right side similarly Acc. No. 100 from table t table and 111 from s table.